# Why is Drone failing to read my username?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, drone.io, gogs

I'm setting up a self-hosted Drone CI server that integrates with a self-hosted Gogs server.

I've set up a test repository with the following structure:

```
test/
 |
 *- add.go
 *- add_test.go
 *- .drone.yml
```

The contents of my `.drone.yml` file is as follows:

```
image: mischief/docker-golang
env:
    - GOPATH=/var/cache/drone
script:
    - go build
    - go test -v
```

Drone was started with the following environment variables (passed with the `-e` flag of `docker run` since both Drone and Gogs are running containerized).

```
"DRONE_GOGS_SKIP_VERIFY=true"
"DRONE_GOGS_URL=http://gogs.sentimens.duckdns.org"
"DRONE_GOGS_SECRET=[redacted]"
"DRONE_GOGS_OPEN=true"
```

When pushing to the new repository, the build is triggered, but fails with the following output:

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --recursive --branch=master http://gogs.sentimens.duckdns.org/drone/test.git /var/cache/drone/src/gogs.sentimens.duckdns.org/drone/test
Cloning into '/var/cache/drone/src/gogs.sentimens.duckdns.org/drone/test'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://gogs.sentimens.duckdns.org': No such device or address
```

What is going on here?  Do I need to specify credentials in the yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository must be public: https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/860

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of Git. That error message was seen in [Gogs issue 717](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/717)

> Probably because git 1.7 does not have the same format for error messages.
>
> Can you try to clone in command line without username or password, to see if you got the same error message like `git clone: fatal: could not read Username for 'http://xxxx.xxx': No such device or address`?

Comment: `docker exec drone echo \`git --version\`` returns `git version 1.9.1`, so it seems as though this isn't the problem.  Nice thought, though!  Much appreciated!  I'm upvoting your answer because it might actually be the correct answer for others.